# ruby, how to structure an if block with AND & OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have the following:

```
<% if !@thread.nil? && @thread.name == 'X' || @thread.name == 'Y' %>
 ....
```

The problem here is that I believe regardless if !@thread.nil?, @thread.name is still be called which is causing errors.

What's the right way to write this so it's like:

```
<% if !@thread.nil? && @thread.name == ('X' || 'Y') %>
```

Some type of contained in a list? for the thread.name?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if !@thread.nil? && ['x','Y'].include?(@thread.name)`

Comment: Thanks, tried that and got a  syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Comment: Added parentheses. They're required in this case

Answer (score 4):

`if @thread.present? and ['X', 'Y'].include?(@thread.name)`

Edit: [More info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) on `#present?`.

Comment: An object is present if it’s not blank or nil

Comment: Can present be used for a field?

Comment: for anything, even `nil.present?`

Comment: `irb(main):027:0> nil.present?
NoMethodError: undefined method 'present?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: It's monkey patched by Rails, not built in by Ruby itself.
`› rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
>> nil.present?
=> false
`

Comment: @Prabesh Shrestha: try running `nil.methods` then ;) Everything's an Object in Ruby.

Comment: @Prabesh Shrestha Everything in Ruby is an object `nil.class.superclass` returns Object
Edit: he deleted his comment.

Comment: sorry guys. Ya I was mistaken thats why I deleted my answer. nil has ancestry of [NilClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] . but present is not an instance method of any of those I guess. Thats why nil.present? returns NoMethodError .

Comment: @Prabesh Shrestha: Chris explained it in his comment, and added some info to the answer as well. `present?` method is not present(:P) in vanilla Ruby. It's added by Rails. I didn't know that, since I haven't had the opportunity to work with Rails yet.

Answer (score 3):

The try method could make this code more clearer. Take a look at this http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html.

Answer (score 3):

```
['x', 'Y'].include?(@thread.try(:name))
```

or

```
['x', 'Y'].include? @thread.try :name
```